# ionic emulate ios - won't emulate and says no such file or directory

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Ran `add ios` and `build ios` fine, but then I ran `ionic emulate ios` and it brought up the `xcode` emulator but with no app or button for my app (just safari, maps, etc.).

I then later ran `ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-5s"` and got this error:

```
  BUILD SUCCEEDED 

 An error was encountered processing the command
 (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159): Invalid device
 state An error was encountered processing the command
 (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159): Invalid device
 state

 ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
 '/Users/sh/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/62773263-27DC-4E83-9C6A-ED2B73DC3F0A/system.log'
 Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args:
 launch,/Users/sh/Desktop/shapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/shapp.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s,--stderr,/Users/sh/Desktop/shapp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/sh/Desktop/shapp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
 Error: /Users/sh/Desktop/shapp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command
 failed with exit code 2

 SHs-iMac:shapp sh$ q
 -bash: q: command not found
```

Not sure what I did wrong as I added and built ios correctly.

It also worked correctly when pulled up in xcode although there are these warnings for both running with [5s and 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvuIP.png). I think it is an ionic issue not being able to emulate ios just not sure how to fix it?

Comment: Try updating the `ios-sim` package: `npm install ios-sim -g`

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix everything and now it is running on both 5s and 6, but I still am getting this error even though run succeeded for both:

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
** RUN SUCCEEDED **

Comment: try updating cordova, rm ios platform and adding it again. 1. `cordova platform rm ios` 2. `npm install -g cordova` 3. `cordova platform add ios`

Comment: Thank you, when I ran cordova platform rm ios and cordova platform add ios I got this error "Error: Platform "iOS" not recognized as a core cordova platform. See `cordova platform list`." When I ran npm install -g cordova I got this message " npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm", if it is deprecated how else do I update it? It seems to run correctly in the emulator now, just still getting those errors. If I ignore them, will those errors mess me up when I try to publish the apps later on or be an issue?

Comment: But you could add iOS as a platform? You have to run `cordova platform add ios` not `iOS`. If you don't have the platform you can't build the project unless you build it in the cloud using http://docs.ionic.io/docs/package-ios for example

Comment: Thanks, my bad, yes so cordova platform add ios worked, I ran cordova platform rm ios and it didn't do anything,nothing ran, now when I run ionic emulate ios I don't get the errors just "No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.2 simulator..." so it seems to be working. Thanks again.

Comment: great! Just wrote it as an answer. Glad that it worked

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help!

Comment: @MatiTucci if you don't mind I have one other question: I then did "ionic emulate ios -cls" and the ionic app has been spinning in the xcode emulator for an hr now without loading. In the terminal it says build succeeded and there are no errors. I quit xcode and restarted it before running this so not sure what is going on? Do you have any ideas/suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I always run: `ionic run ios` and if you don't have a device connected the sim opens. Try `ionic run ios` just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

1. Update `ios-sim` package: `npm install ios-sim -g`
2. Update cordova: `npm install -g cordova`
3. Remove iOS platform: `ionic platform rm ios`
4. Add iOS platform: `ionic platform add ios`

Comment: for "Add iOS platform"  is ionic platform add ios